# Python: edit a specific string format in text files "UNLESS/EXCEPT"

Tags: python, regex, string, text, except

The following is in my script to find strings such as `dd/dd/dd` in text files and edit them.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"([0-9]{1,4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,4})")
```

Is there a way to specify this to edit the specified string UNLESS if/EXCEPT when preceded or followed by additional `d/` or `/d`, respectively?

I tried the following and it did not work.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"([^\d\/][0-9]{1,4}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{2,4}[^\/\d])")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some input and expected output strings.

Comment: Put `\b` at each end of the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I saw that post but I didn't see the connection.. ha I'm not CS, probably went over my head.. I'll read it again

Comment: The lookarounds in that thread do the job, just put `(?<!\d)` in front and `(?!\d)` at the end of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use r"(\d{1,4}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,4})" to handle better the regex with digits.